# Regex - PHP - match multi level URL path if beginning is followed by certain path or nothing else

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to create a regex to match a certain part of a URL path, however admittedly with very little previous regex experience and after reading up various regex tutorials for a couple of hours, I seem to be stuck. My error is probably something very simple at this point, but I'm not even sure what to search for and what type of regex operator that I need (I looked at a whole bunch of other questions, and while some were similar, I didn't find an exact match).

I have to match any URL path below:

**/services

/services/

/services/page/2

/services/page/140/**

But it should not match any of these below:

/service/page
/servicesx/page
/services/page
/services/page/
/services/pages
/services/pages/2/
/services/foo
/services/foo/page

I need to match a slash / followed by "services", optionally followed by slash and then either follow exactly by page and slash and any number of digits and optional trailing slash or if not followed by exactly that, then nothing else should follow.

A number should always follow "page", otherwise "page" following "services" without a number is also invalid, and nothing else should follow "services".

I've been using this tool for experimenting:
https://regex101.com/

So far I've come up with this regex, which doesn't work as it still matches too much (it matches "/services/").

```
\/\bservices\b\/?(?:page\/[0-9]+)?\/?
```

I'll need to use the regex in PHP, if that matters.

[image: regex matching too much]

Comment: Are these values strings in their own right or substrings in a larger text?

Comment: @Nick each line is a string on its own right - using parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) to get the values.

Comment: Then you just need to add anchors `^` and `$` to the regex. Also note that your `\b` are redundant as the `/` before and after `services` implies that `\b` will be true. See https://regex101.com/r/8DP6PL/1

Comment: @Nick awesome, I knew it must've been something simple, I guess my brain is too fried by now... but then again, I never could "get" regex. That's exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: No worries. Note if you change your delimiters (e.g. to `#`) you won't need to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: @Nick good point, helps readability. Feel free to post this as an answer so that I can accept it, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is missing start and end-of-string anchors, which is why it matches `/services/` in the URLs that you don't want to match. Additionally, you don't need the `\b` assertions in it, as the `/` before and after `services` implies that `\b` will be true. Finally, if you change your delimiter (e.g. to `~`), you won't need to escape the forward slashes in the regex. This will do what you want:

```
^/services/?(?:page/[0-9]+)?/?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8DP6PL/2/)